# Unknown escape sequence warning when using '\/'

Tags: iphone, string, date, escaping

I need to send a date as a string to a webserver with the following notation:

**/Date(1332843997553+0200)/**

Within my code I'm achieving this as follows with startdate as a 'long long' type:

```
NSString *DateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\/Date(%qi%@)\/", startdate,timezone];
```

However the notation mentioned above gives me the following warning " Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - Unknown escape sequence '/' ".

Anyone got a clue how I can get rid of this warning without changing the DateString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to put a backslash in front of /:

```
@"/Date(%qi%@)/"
```

unless you really want **\/Date()\/** :

```
@"\\/Date(%qi%@)\\/"
```